# Получить чистые данные из массива

Tags: массивы, php

Подскажите. как из массива

```
$id = {"id":"123456"}
```

Получить только 123456 =)

Answer (score 1):

`json_decode()`, однако.

Comment: оооооооооо
Все=) 
Точно. 
Забыл=) 
Спс.